# How to secure Node App from direct access and right way of installing Node

Tags: php, node.js, linux

This is may be a silly question for Node experts but I am confused at this point.

I got a VPS having (Centos) and a php website at example.com. I wanted to run some Node app along with my php website, therefore, I installed `Node.js` in my root directory. For better understanding, here is the directory structure

```
public_html
    -> index.php
    -> style.css
    -> node 
         -> server.js
         -> node_modules
         -> package.lock.json 
         -> package.xml
```

My questions are

1) Is it the right way of installing Node and all Node Modules in Root Directory? If not then where to install Node and its modules? Because I tried installing Node and its modules (socket.io, express etc) out of the root directory like this

```
node 
    -> node_modules
    -> package.lock.json     
    -> package.xml
public_html
    -> index.php
    -> style.css
    -> server.js
```

and then running `node server.js` located in my root directory but it could not run because some modules like socket.io was not found which I had required in server.js.

2) How can I protect my Node app `server.js`? Because anyone can access it through browser direct address e.g.

```
 https://example.com/server.js
```

and this will show all the plain code just like a normal javascript file.

Thanking in anticipation for any kind help.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, **NO**.

You should deploy your application to an non-public folder like `/opt/yourapplication`. I will consider creating a user `yourapplicationuser` with a limited set of rights, and make this user owner of your application folder. Then run your application as this user.

To answer the second question, **there's nothing to protect**, as the nodejs application won't share a directory and its files but instead provide with an actual HTTP server implementation that will listen for incoming requests on a given/configured port.

To share the port `80` for both PHP and NodeJS applications, which I can understad is your goal. You'll have to configure a reverse proxy (which can be your actual httpd server) that based on the route redirects the traffic to the NodeJS application listening in some other local port ie: `8081`.

I think the steps reflected in [this guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-node-app-to-digital-ocean), might help you on your journey.

Comment: The link you provided is really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: You can protect your server.js file by adding it to your robots.txt as disallowed:

```
Disallow: /server.js
```

Comment: I don't think robot.txt is used to prevent access to any file nor it is the purpose of robot.txt other than guidelines for web crawlers. However, you gave me an idea, I can prevent access with `.htaccess`, as I think. Not tried yet. But again my question remains what is the standard way for Node app itself.